# Decrypting environmental variables in AWS Lambda not working in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, python-3.6

I have encrypted an environmental variable in an AWS Lambda function with an AWS KMS. Then I have tried to decrypt the variable in code using the example code that AWS provides, which adapted to my variable is the following:

```
import os
import boto3
from base64 import b64decode

keys = {}
def get_variable(variable):
    encrypted = os.environ[f'{variable}']
    decrypted = boto3.client('kms').decrypt(CiphertextBlob=b64decode(encrypted))['Plaintext']
    keys[variable] = decrypted

get_variable('port')

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    port = keys['port']
    return port
```

I have tested the function but it throw out the next error:

```
An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: b'5934' is not JSON serializable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 110, in decimal_serializer
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: b'5934' is not JSON serializable
```

However, switching Lambda from Python 3.6 to Python 3.7 make it works perfectly. Is there any way to solve it so that I do not have to change my python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following. It just makes sure the function is returning a string, which is JSON serializable instead of bytes, which are not.

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    port = keys['port']
    return str(port)
```

Comment: It has worked. I have had to add an encoding though return str(port, 'utf-8'). Otherwise it appears b'5439

Comment: Thank you @JavierLópezTomás this is the question I was looking to answer when I came across this SO question